# Left and right gradients of an absolute function

Tags: vector-analysis, absolute-value

I need to find left and right partial derivatives of the following function.

$$
\Phi (x_1, x_2) = \vert x_2 - x_1 \vert \ \text{on} \ \mathbb{R}^2
$$

The first question is to prove $\Phi$ is convex, which I can do. The second is to find left and right gradients and see if the gradient exists. My attempt:

$$
x_2 \ge x_1 \implies \vert x_2 - x_1 \vert = x_2 - x_1
$$

$$
x_2 \le x_1 \implies \vert x_2 - x_1 \vert = - x_2 + x_1
$$
The left gradient as $x$ approach $0$ is ($x_1 \le x_2$):
$$
D\Phi_{-} (0) = [ -1 \ 1]
$$
The right gradient as $x$ approach $0$ is ($x_1 \ge x_2$):
$$
D\Phi_{-} (0) = [ 1 \ -1]
$$
Since the left is not equal to the right, the gradient does not exist. Is this a right way to prove this?

Comment: I've never heard of a left/right gradient (that could easily be my own ignorance). Do you have a definition of what they mean? A left/right derivative makes sense for functions on $\Bbb{R}$, but I don't see a natural generalisation to $\Bbb{R}^2$.

Comment: The left-gradient of $\Phi$ at $x_0$ is the vector of left-partial derivatives at $x_0$. The right-gradient is defined analogously.

Answer (score 1):

The one-sided  partial derivatives exist at all points. The right derivative of $\Phi$ w.r.t. $x_1$  at $(x_1,x_2)$ is $1$ for $x_1  \geq x_2$ and $-1$ for $x_1 <x_2$. [ For example in the second case we get $\lim_{h \to 0+} \frac {(-x_1-h+x_2)-(-x_1+x_2)} h =-1$]. Similarly, the left derivative of $\Phi$ w.r.t. $x_1$ at $(x_1,x_2)$ is $-1$ for $x_1  \geq x_2$ and $1$ for $x_1 <x_2$. The partial derivatives w.r.t. $x_2$ are similar.

Comment: For your example, you took the partial derivative with respect to $x_1$, right? Because my understanding is that the left and right gradients in this case are vectors with 2 elements, where each element is an one-sided partial derivative.

Comment: @dunguyen Yes, I forgot to mention that I was computing the first partial derivatives. You can compute the second partials also in  a similar fashion and all one sided derivatives exist at all points.